# Setting up QtCreator with OpenCV

Tags: qt, opencv, qt-creator

Trying to set up Opencv in QtCreator, `CV.H` and `HIGHUI.H` are not recognized.
I found a [tutorial](http://opencvstart.blogspot.dk/2012/12/configure-opencv-24-for-qt-creator-on.html) saying that I need to add the following code to the .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
LIBS += -lopencv_ml
LIBS += -lopencv_video
LIBS += -lopencv_features2d
LIBS += -lopencv_calib3d
LIBS += -lopencv_objdetect
LIBS += -lopencv_contrib
LIBS += -lopencv_legacy
LIBS += -lopencv_flann
LIBS += -lopencv_nonfree
```

I guess the problem is that if I go to `/usr/local/include/opencv` folder or `/usr/local/lib` folder they are completely empty.
I am sure OpenCV is installed correctly because I have been working on Eclipse for a while with OpenCV.

I found that probably I have to change `/usr/local/include/opencv` with `/usr/iclude/opencv2` (existing folder) but then I have no idea what to change the `/usr/local/lib` folder with.

Comment: Have you tried `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/opencv2` and `LIBS += /usr/lib/...`?

Comment: Please explain what does not work. :)